# Apache Flink CI/CD--Kubernetes--Github

Tags: continuous-integration, apache-flink, cd, kubernetes

Has someone successfully run Flink jobs with this kind of setup (Github CI CD and Kubernetes)?
Since Flink jobs can’t be dockerized and deployed in a natural way as part
 of the container  I am not very sure of how is the
 best way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be done. For the dockerizing portion, see the the docs about [running Flink on Docker](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/docker.html) and [running Flink on Kubernetes](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/ops/deployment/kubernetes.html), as well as [Patrick Lukas' Flink Forward talk on "Flink in Containerland"](https://berlin.flink-forward.org/kb_sessions/flink-in-containerland/). You'll find links to docker hub, github, slideshare, and youtube behind these links.

[dA Platform 2](https://data-artisans.com/da-platform-2) is a commercial offering from data Artisans that supports CI/CD integrations for Flink on Kubernetes. The [demo video from the product announcement at Flink Forward Berlin 2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOZqh5pQcKM&t=15m32s) illustrates this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this stuff. Flink jobs can be dockerized and deployed in a natural way as part of the container.

I extend flink Docker and added "Flink run "some.jar"" step to it.

It works perfect

https://github.com/Aleksandr-Filichkin/flink-k8s